# transferring files without duplicate

Tags: file-transfer, data-transfer, duplicate

Lets say I am hosting servers where users put files and at the end of the day all these files are retrieved into a storing server.

The problem is that lots of those files will be duplicate and I want to avoid having to copy 10 times the same files.

I was thinking about getting a hash for each files that transit to be sure that each one are unique, but maybe there is better solutions.

Comment: “Files are *retrieved* into a storing server.” This would indicate that the copy process is running on the destination server. In that case you would have to transfer every file anyways in order to generate a hash. The process would have to run on the source server to do what you suggest. What you are looking for is called data deduplication. How it is implemented in your scenario is up to you.

Comment: Using a hash is a reasonable approach, but an understanding of how the duplicates are created may suggest a preferable alternative.

Comment: *The problem is that lots of those files will be duplicate* Does you retrieve all the files into one folder killing directory structure? if not then a copy deletion will cause that the user which' file copy was deleted may loose the access to the file (he may have no permissions or may not to find the copy, especially when it has different name). I think users will not be happy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to separate this into 2 tasks.

First, find the duplicate files on the source machine and create symlinks, shortcuts, or something similar so that the duplicates are represented but do not consume disk space. One option that I have found works very well for finding duplicates is [a well-tuned Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36113168) on SO. It may need to be modified for your use case.

The second step, of course, is to copy the files to the other machine in a way that preserves the symlink or shortcut links.